# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Get'

Tags: python, django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Quote
from .forms import QuoteForm
from pages.models import Page

def quote_req(request):
submitted = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/quote/?submitted=True')
        else:
            form = QuoteForm()
            if 'submitted' in request.Get:
                submitted = True
                
            return render(request, 'quotes/quote.html', {'form': form, 'page_list': Page.objects.all(), 'submitted':submitted})
```

Context: This is the views.py code the code looks correct but clicking on the quote link on the html local host gives the aforementioned error

Comment: It should be `request.GET` (uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

You have just a typo:

```
            if 'submitted' in request.Get:
```

Use `request.GET` instead.

Answer (score 0):

i know it been a while, but i can help others that run into the same issue

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Quote
from .forms import QuoteForm
from pages.models import Page

def quote_req(request):
submitted = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/quote/?submitted=True')
    else:
            form = QuoteForm()
            if 'submitted' in request.Get:
                submitted = True
                
            return render(request, 'quotes/quote.html', {'form': form, 'page_list': Page.objects.all(), 'submitted':submitted})
```

This is what i did.
Make sure the second else that is below ``` if request.method == "POST":